# Printing firestore object

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to print a firestore object? While working with AngularFire i'm attempting to print to html the name of the document in the firestore. My firestore has a parent "nforms" which has two children as documents "pdf","img", inside pdf i have one pdf called "norcal-letterhead.pdf", inside img i have one img called "git-img.jpg".

This is how I am pulling the data form the firestore.

```
fptr: Observable<any[]>;
fileData: DocumentReference[];
fileCollection: DocumentReference;
filePtr: Observable<any>;
constructor(firestore: AngularFirestore, firestorage: AngularFireStorage) {
    this.filePtr = firestore.collection('nforms').valueChanges();
    this.filePtr.subscribe(
        data => {
            this.fileData = data
            console.log(this.fileData)
            this.fileData.map(r => this.fileCollection = r)
            console.log(this.fileCollection)
        }
    );
}
```

This is how I am printing the data from the pull.

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of filePtr|async">
<td *ngIf="fileCollection; let a">{{a}} or {{data}}</td></tr>
```

I'm getting back this: [object Object] or [object Object]

[image: firestore structure]

This is the response that i'm getting from the console. As you can see i'm able to pull what looks like an Array of 2 with objects of type DocumentReference. 
[image: firestore console]

Comment: What do you mean by `print a firestore object`?

Comment: I am referring to the way firestore is saving a collection of data. Please view my screenshot, nforms.component.ts.114, (2) [{...},{...}], i believe that those two items that look like this {...} each represent an object. Right below in the screenshot, it also shows that they're of type DocumentReference.

Comment: I should also mention, the way I initially setup my firestore was using the console, that's what was returning to me this data. However, after many hours later I decided to follow the [angular firestore sdk documentations](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/storage/storage.md). In doing so, I was able to upload and download my data correctly. Still, I'm curious if google firebase has a way of reading back a simple pdf that's uploaded using their upload button to an empty database. It will model the data as mentioned above, [{...}] of type DocumentReference.

Comment: I still have no idea what you mean with `print a firestore object`. I can see the pictures yes, but have no idea what you actually want. But if you solved it, nice! :)

Comment: If you have an empty cloudstore and you create (using the console) a collection that has two documents as such, nforms -> document-id -> attributes, then the sdk returns back (2)[{...},{...}], as seen in the screenshot. How does one read those items? How does one "print" in your HTML view? Apologies for the confusion there, this isn't JAVA lol :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to share some more insigh on this post for future reference to whomever it could help. While this isn't the answer to printing the firestore objects that were created from using the console 'upload' button, this is an answer to printing the same objects except this time i created them through the sdk '.upload'.

Define the object FireStore Item:

```
export interface fstoreitem{
    form_id: string;
    form_name: string;
    form_path: string;
}
```

Define the firestore reference to a collection nforms:

```
constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore){
 this.fitemCollection = firestore.collection<fstoreitem>('nforms/');
 this.fitem = this.fitemCollection.valueChanges();
}
```

Define the routine to upload a firestore item:

```
addStoreItem(form_name: string, form_path: string) {
 const form_id = this.firestore.createId();
 const form_item: fstoreitem = { form_id, form_name, form_path };
 this.fitemCollection.doc(form_id).set(form_item);
}
```

Display the objects in the view:

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of fitem | async">
 <td>{{data.form_name}}</td>
 <td><a href="{{data.form_path}}">download</a></td>
</tr>
```